# Console application for webpage JAVASCRIPT (no debugging)

Tags: javascript, console

im learning basics of javascript in Codecademy , and did a simple text game, the thing is: I want to expand it and make it more enjoyable.

**I want the game does not use pop-ups to be displayed I want a console in the browser that you type stuff in a bar and when you hit enter the command is send to do stuff like...**

Did some research before this and found this [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001203/javascript-console-application) BUT this console is really hard to understand for a beginner like me, there is a easy way to make a console for javascript?

Comment: What is "*console in a browser*"? Please explain.

Comment: You may attempt to solve the problem, and when you get to a point where you cannot proceed, you may post a question here with a sample code. Then, someone may help you.

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking how to make a textbox and a button?

Comment: The question you linked to has a good one from moonshadow called jqueryterminal.

Comment: ok ok , sorry for not being clear about it, i hit enter and send the question incomplete, yes the example is good, but there is a simpler way to make a console in the browser? (not the console that appears when you use "inspect element")

Comment: darn, thought that hittin' enter would make a new line on this comment... well, Brendan in the answer I linked created a nice console, BUT thats a lot of code, and i want to understand what im doing, long story short: Simple windowed console that has limited height for text , (look at Brendan console: text go way up in the sky!) and to go up or down use "repág" and "avpág" im using spanish keyboard, sorry for that. more details soon, i have to go now.

Comment: @Slaks probably, i can just make a text box and type stuff in it, really simple stuff, i dont want a button i want something like the windows cmd console that black box with white text... you click, type stuff, hit enter , and the console recive the command to do stuff... i have no idea how to make the textbox make output stuff on a little screen on the webpage. need help, im just a beginner. thanks.

Comment: @user3755721: You need to learn the basics of HTML, Javascript, and CSS.  (in particular, keydown events and the DOM)

Comment: I know HTML a bit of javascript and some CSS thanks for the "keydown events and DOM" stuff , going to post process in some time.